# How to set a unique id for tags made by iteration through an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I am fetching the data from Chrome storage and I want to iterate through that data.
So I am using map and making a p tag with an id ="getId".

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, tabs => {
  const fullUrl = tabs[0].url;

  const url = fullUrl.split("?")[0];

  chrome.storage.local.get("scroll-mark", data => {
    const scrollMarkData = data["scroll-mark"];
    if (scrollMarkData && scrollMarkData.hasOwnProperty(url)) {
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML =
        "Continue from where you last left or update/delete scrroll for this page.";
      document.getElementById(
        "activeContol"
      ).innerHTML = `<img src="./images/icon-32.png" />`;
      root.innerHTML = `
      <div style="margin-top:25px">
      <div style="margin-bottom:10px;display:flex;justify-content:center;width:100%;">
      <button id="getScroll" style="width:100%;" class="btn">Fetch Scroll</button>
      </div>
      <div style="display:flex; width:285 px; margin-top:-5px">
      <button class="btn orange" style="width:100%;margin-right:10px" id="saveScroll">Update</button>
      <button class="btn red" style="width:100%;" id="deleteScroll">Delete</button>
      </div>
      <div id="addScroll"><p style="font-size:16px; cursor:pointer; color:white">Add More scrolls</p></div>
      
          ${Object.keys(scrollMarkData[url]).map(v => {
          return `<p id="getId" style="font-size: 12px;color:white">${v}</p>`
        }).join('')}
      
      <div>`
```

So I what I am expecting is that only when **I click on any particular p tag, I get the alert displaying the innerHTML of that tag**. But it is not happening.

```
       let getMultipleScroll = document.getElementById("getId");
      getMultipleScroll.onclick = function (element) {
        alert(getMultipleScroll.innerHTML)
      }
      chrome.storage.local.set({
        "get-multiple-scroll": getMultipleScroll.innerHTML
      })
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `${Object.keys(scrollMarkData[url]).map((v,i) => \`<p id="getId${i}" style="font-size: 12px;color:white">${v}</p>\`).join('')}`

Comment: And what changes I have to make in 'document.getElementById('getId')' ?? @JaromandaX

Comment: appropriate ones

Comment: @PratyushNarain if you are following along the comment of @Jaromanda, Then you need to get each element by looping over and selecting the ids `"getId0"` to `"getId${n}"` so `n` is the last index, and each time add that event listener, or you can use event delegation instead and that's the best solution here, so adding only one click event listener to the parent of those p elements `id="addScroll"` and check if the `event.target.nodeName === "P"` then `alert(e.target.innerHTML)`

Comment: I am not getting..Where  and how I have to loop over the ids?

Comment: What do u mean by appropriate ones? Can you plz explain @JaromandaX

Comment: Ok I figured it out Thank you very much